# Facebook Activity Feed not listing activity

Tags: javascript, facebook, android-activity, facebook-social-plugins

Any April Wine fans out there???? I am the webmaster for their website and I am desperately trying to find a solution to this problem.

I want to ADD the Facebook Social plugin "Activity Feed" to the band's website.

I used the code generator (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/) for the social pluggin, and embedded the code into my website's source code.

Here is the code I place in the BODY section of my HTML code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I then paste this code into the desired area on my website:

```
<div class="fb-activity" data-site="www.facebook.com/groups/2379953649/" data-width="587" data-height="350" data-header="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-border-color="orange" data-recommendations="false"></div>
```

The activity box does appear on my page, but it will not list the activity of my Facebook Group.

All it reads is:

**"No recent activity to display.
Put some Like buttons on your website to engage your users. Details can be found here."**

There is activity on my facebook group, so I am completely stumped as to why it will not pick up on this activity and list it in the Activity Feed box that I embedded.

Any HELP would be GREATLY appreciated. I have tried to read up on this, but cannot find any documentation that will help me.

Dave

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you are still struggling with this issue or not - but perhaps this will help...  I think perhaps the activity feed isn't exactly what you think it is.  It seems that it isn't a feed of all the activity on the band's facebook page, rather, it is all the facebook activity generated from the domain. So, if you don't have a way for users to interact with facebook from your site than it won't generate any data.

EDIT

Perhaps the facebook like box would work better:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue as you.
I'm using the iframe version of the activity plugin , and it seems that I'm obtaining the same response.

My research pointed me to the facebook fan page permissions, may you please check the permissions of the fan page (or group page).

Here's the link that I found.

[Facebook Social Plugin Not Working](http://www.profromgo.com/facebook-social-plugin-working-logged-users%20Facebook%20Social%20Plugin%20Not%20Working)

If that is not the case, the other work around that I'm working, is to create a very simple facebook web application, and using the new javascript api, I will just pull the posts from the graph.
The downside of this, is that the user will need to log in, though, I don't know if there's an easy way out to work with the graph without login, since it beats the purpose of using the plugin that doesn't needs the log in.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Activity Feed Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      FB.init({
        appId: here-you-put-your-app-id,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        oauth: true
      });
      FB.login(function(response){
      FB.api('/your-fan-page-facebook-entity-here/posts', {limit: 20}, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that it helps.
(In the console log, you will find the response from the activity, I just need the posts )

Comment: What ended up using was the like box pluggin , seemed to work Ok and can actually fetch the feeds from the facebook pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed with the activity box that if you are using a Facebook ID with admin privileges for the site, which is quite likely, then it won't display anything. The first thing to try is just set up the Activity widgit, then view it using a non-admin FB profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems, although I'm trying to get it to display any activity not just a specific page's activity. Anyways, one thing that I have discovered is that for the 'data-site' tag you need to use a domain (ex. www.facebook.com), using 'www.facebook.com/groups/2379953649/' doesn't seem to work because it is giving more info than just the domain, subdomains (ex. graph.facebook.com) will also work, but the domain needs to have facebook activity, ie. a link has been shared from that site on facebook, etc.

Sorry for the wordy answer, hope it helps, and if anyone notices that anything I have stated is incorrect please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Its like, I have also observed such cases... but I think the activity feed will only work properly if there is ample traffic that shares and likes your articles.